# getViewTreeObserver for 2 views

Tags: android

Haven't found something to understand how to use it correctly.

I need to measure 2 views.
For first view i use this:

```
 viewPager.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //my measure code
                viewPager.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
 });
```

So what should i do for second view: i should use another same block of code, but for second view or can i put second measurement inside viewpager's measurements?

Added: logically it can be different cases:

- One view inside another view.
- Two views near each other in same parent (viewObserver on first view).
- Two views near each other in same parent (viewObserver on parent).